# How to index and search CVS repository

Tags: version-control, documentation, cvs

In my company, we use CVS to store all kind of files, from source code to office files with requirements documentation, presentations etc. Basically everything that is a file ends up in the CVS repository.

I'm aware that this is not a good practice.

Anyway, my question is: is there some kind of tool or application that i can use to index my CVS repository and provide search on doc, xls, pdf documents and so on? Needs to be a web application so i can use it from my tablet or phone.

I found a lot of DMS of course, but none of them seem to have a way to connect to a CVS repository, or at least connect to a folder in a filesystem. You are required to upload each file by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to CVS, but you could set up [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (which in turn uses [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)). This is a web front end to your own search engine, so you could get it to index a checked-out folder.

Of course, you'll have to make sure the necessary security is in place if you wish to access this remotely (e.g. from your phone).

Comment: I also looked into Apache Solr, and seemed to be a bit complicated to setup, but i will take another look. Thank you.